# What happened to Jessie Quick?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, arrow

In season 8 episode 1 of *Arrow* it is seen that

> the Anti-monitor destroys Earth-2, where Jessie​ Quick lives.

So, what happened to Jessie Quick and HR as a consequence of this event?

Comment: Seeing that the episode aired this week, and that this will most likely be answered in the episodes to come, I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based for now.

Comment: I would assume she is gone because of the ending of episode 3.

Comment: Most probably but not definitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In season 6 episode 10 of **The Flash** Cisco mentions that all of the Earth 2 is wiped off and Harry and Jesse are gone forever, and considering the fact that he must have said this after running a lot of investigation it is safe to say that *Jesse Quick* died in the crisis.

Comment: Until she is "speedforced" back in to existence of course.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4613/49).